# How can I read accented characters in ruby shoes?

Tags: ruby, encoding, diacritics, shoes

I can't do a very simple thing in ruby shoes.
The code is the seguent:

```
#encoding:UTF-8
Shoes.app do
@var = File.readlines('temp.txt')
para @var
end
```

If in the txt there is a word with an accented character, the code doesn't work. Shoes says "not a valid UTF8 string"
How can I solve this problem???

edit: the result is the same if I remove the line `#encoding:UTF-8`

Comment: Is it a valid UTF-8 string? If yes, then there is something wrong with Shoes. If not, then there are two obvious solutions: make it a valid UTF-8 string or read it with the correct encoding.

Comment: the word can be "accènt", "accént" or any other word that contains a regular accent. It seems that shoes doesn't read the file in utf8.

Comment: Is the file in UTF-8?

Comment: it is a simple .txt. how can I set the encoding?

Comment: Did you write the file?  If so, rewrite the file doing this: `File.open('temp.txt', 'w', encoding: "UTF-8" ) do |f|`

Comment: In order to set the encoding you have to know what the encoding is. So, let me ask again: is the file encoded as UTF-8? If not, what encoding is it encoded in? It makes no sense to set the encoding unless you know what encoding to set.

Comment: I found that if I read the file as ISO-8859-1 I don't have problems. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
#encoding:UTF-8
```

only governs the characters you use for your actual code.  And if you are using a recent version of ruby, it does nothing because by default ruby code is assumed to be written with UTF-8 characters.

> edit: the result is the same if I remove the line #encoding:UTF-8

Yes, that's because you are probably using a recent version of ruby, and that is the default.

You have to know the encoding of the file you want to read.  If the file is  encoded in ISO-8859-1, you can do:

```
@var = File.readlines('temp.txt', encoding: "ISO-8859-1")
```

What characters are in your file?  What do you get when you do this:

```
$ ruby -e"puts Encoding.default_external"
```

Comment: If i read the file as ISO-8859-1 I don't have problems.Thank you for your help!